# Passing data from the active tab in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I am a newbie creating an extension.

I wanted to send `window.document` from an **active tab** to my react app. I am doing it like below:

`manifest.json`

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "UI ",
  "description": "test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "storage"],
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "default-src 'self'; connect-src https://* data: blob: filesystem:;"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

```
// content.js

// Send the document content to the background script
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
  action: "getDocumentContent",
  content: document.documentElement.outerHTML,
});
```

```
// background.js

// Function to handle messages from content script
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (message.action === "getDocumentContent") {
    // Update the state with the document content received from content script
    chrome.storage.local.set({ documentContent: message });
  }
});
```

And then in my react hook:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { displayChildTagNames } from "./utils";

export const useNodes = (setActiveTag: any) => {
  const [nodes, setNodes] = useState<string | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (chrome.storage) {
      // extension
      chrome.storage.local.get("documentContent", function (data) {
        setNodes(data.documentContent.content || "");
      });
    } else {
      // locally
      setNodes(document.documentElement.outerHTML || "");
      console.error("chrome.storage is not available.");
    }

    return () => {
      setNodes(null);
    };
  }, []);

  const jsxTags = displayChildTagNames(nodes ?? "", setActiveTag);

  return jsxTags;
};
```

It is more or less working but not as I expect. It is sending the `window.document` but only **from the 1st tab I open**. Even if I switch the tab and open the extension I see `window.document` from the 1st opened tab.

It means that the `content.js` run only once? How to sync to that to send it every time I switch the tab?

Comment: Let your app be the initiator, see this [example](/a/67227376) of using executeScript without the background script or storage or content script.